Cannot login into MariaDB after restarting the machine
I'm using MacOS Sonoma 14.5 and trying to login in mariadb via terminal. However, when I execute
mariadb -uroot -password

It is returning
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I searched online and the solution to this would be to generate a mysql.sock file by executing
brew services start mariadb
# OR brew services restart mariadb

However, I tried it, as you can see below:
$ brew services restart mariadb
Stopping `mariadb`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mariadb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mariadb)
==> Successfully started `mariadb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mariadb)

Still, not any mysql.sock file is generated inside the /tmp folder and I can't login in the mariadb database.
victorcosta@Victors-MacBook-Pro:/tmp $ cd /tmp
victorcosta@Victors-MacBook-Pro:/tmp $ ls
com.apple.launchd.6mj6GfdTiF powerlog

So, how can I connect to mariadb?

Hi! Unfortunately mariadb -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -password returns ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on '127.0.0.1' (36) and mariadb -uroot -password --protocol tcp also returns ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'localhost' (22). Thanks for answering.

Ok then the socket name is different than MySQL.sock, you should look up how it is called in your system

Hi, I already tried to look up this socket in my system with find and no result is found. The temporary solution I'm doing is reinstalling mariadb each time the computer is restarted, because after reinstalling it, the mysql.sock file suddenly appears in the /tmp/ folder and mysql -uroot works. Still, this is clearly not the ideal solution, because I'm loosing all my MySQL tables data after reinstalling the database each time the computer is restarted.

sockets can be viewed by https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/207240/os-x-list-all-active-sockets

Hi @nbk, I just ran netstat. However no mysql or mariadb socket is being displayed on it's output. This is happening even after running brew services start mariadb and receiving the message ==> Successfully started mariadb (label: homebrew.mxcl.mariadb).

please show your mysql.cnf and the error log, which should show us what is running.

I found my.cnf file at /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf. The output is:
# Location: /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
basedir = /opt/homebrew/opt/mariadb
datadir = /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
log-error = /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/Victors-MacBook-Pro.local.err
pid-file = /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/Victors-MacBook-Pro.local.pid
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

[client]
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock


@nbk I took a look at the error file (Victors-MacBook-Pro.local.err) and noticed there are lines showing ERROR signs. Here are them:
2024-11-20  3:49:43 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing FILE_CHECKPOINT(3988979434) at 3988979434
2024-11-20  3:49:43 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Log scan aborted at LSN 3988979434
2024-11-20  3:49:43 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2024-11-20  3:49:43 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2024-11-20  3:49:43 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2024-11-20  3:49:43 0 [ERROR] Aborting
